# How to incorporate excel file name with pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, sql-server, excel, pandas, dataframe

I'm pretty new to Pandas Dataframe. I'm able to import excel sheet into DataFrame but couldn't exactly figure out how to incorporate the file name with the existing dataframe values. Also need to insert the final dataframe into SQL server. My scripts below, any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!!:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
df = pd.read_excel("C:\Data\Me\me\Resume\PriviaHealth\PythonTestQuestions\Privia Family Medicine 113018.xlsx", header=None, skiprows=3, usecols = 'B,I:M')
df.head(5)

import os
globbed_files = glob.glob("*.xlsx") #creates a list of all excel files
data = []                      # pd.concat takes a list of dataframes as an agrument
for excel in globbed_files:
    frame = pd.read_excel(excel)
    frame['filename'] = os.path.basename(excel)
    data.append(frame)

#Insert into SQL Server
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc
connStr = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};SERVER=10.247.166.133;DATABASE=PersonDatabase;Trusted_Connection=yes')
cursor = connStr.cursor()

for index,row in df.iterrows():
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO dbo.Demographics([ID],[FirstName],[MiddleName][LastName],[DOB],[Sex],[FavoriteColor]) 
                         values (?, ?,?)", row['ID'], 
                                           row['FirstName'],
                                           row['MiddleName'],
                                           row['LastName'],
                                           row['DOB'],
                                           row['Sex'],
                                           row['FavoriteColor'],
                       row[globbed_files]) 
connStr.commit()
cursor.close()
connStr.close()
```